# Provide free tag based adverts for Area 51 proposals that are in commit phase on other sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51

If we take the GIS proposal, it needs more experienced users; it is likely that there are lot of people on StackOverflow that are writing GIS software.  Some of these would commit, if they knew about the GIS proposal.

I don’t know how to control the adverts or decide what tags to run them on etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea behind Area 51 and SE 2.0, is that you already have a community. It shouldn't be SE team that has to go out and gather people for proposals, it should be you.

In the end you shouldn't be too worried about the commit %. The new sites is going to be created by the SE team and not an algorithm to calculate a score. What you should worry about is the number of committers you have, that haven't gotten the 50 point you get for verifying your email address and actually count in the score.

Comment: the problem is you need a community that have rep on other sites, otherwise there commitment is not taken to mean match

Comment: @Ian: It's only the first sites they require a lot of high rep users. They need to make sure that the sites will have an active community when it's launched. Eventually, they may change the algorithm when they find out, how active 1 rep users will be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's appropriate for the commit phase.

However, note that **public beta sites** do get free house ad space on Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault …

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/3816/se2publicbetahousead.png

… like so.

Comment: Can those ads be limited to (or weighted towards) specific tags on SOFU? For instance, the WordPress Answers site would like to target ads towards the wordpress tag on SOFU sites: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-can-we-better-promote-this-site-and-attract-more-users/180#180

Comment: Is there an algorithm used to serve the ads?  I am referring to something along the lines of ["rads"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/summary-of-amazon-remnant-ad-experiment/).

Comment: The image is dead, unless you have it still somewhere stored, can the answer do without the image?